# JdbcIO or custom sink to use specific database bulk utility

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to know how complex it would be to implement a custom sink for a PostgreSQL database. In this sense, instead of the default batch of 1000 INSERTs, I would like to use Java's Copy Manager. I believe this would result in faster writes since I'd be using a Postgresql own data loading utility.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as writing your own `ParDo` that uses whatever utilities you like to achieve the functionality:

- Authoring IOs:  https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/
- Details about `ParDos`: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo

In case of `JdbcIO` the `Write` `PTransform` is [implemented in under 200 lines](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java#L689)  and allows you to [configure the batch size](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java#L712), you can use it as an example.

And if this is something Beam users can possibly benefit from, consider [contributing it into Beam](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/) as well.